# Apache2 with php-fpm error_log setup

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm, error-log

I have a script located in `home/user/public_html/scrip/sript.php` .
What I want is that when I run the script and there are errors an `error_log.txt` file to be generated in the same location as the script.

The errors are generated but in a common location for all services but I want to know if it's possible to setup this for a specific location of a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the script from the shell?  Then `2>` will echo the errors to a file you name.  so `php sript.php 2> sript.err` creates an error log

Comment: Hi, The script is not running from the shell. I have to mention that it worked just fine before switching to easyapachhe 4.

Comment: Did all errors for all php programs go to a 'custom' directory?  then its in the php.ini file, (or the linux httpd.conf file)

Comment: Thank you for your messageNo. I want this setup only for this script. The others go to the custom location setup in httpd.conf